Android: Is it possible to update the ContentProvider URIs on runtime?
I am newbie in Android, and as I see, the MyContentProvider declared in the AndroidManifest.xml is created at the beginning of the app, when launched. But not by my code, is created by android. So I don't have access to the variable that holds the Java Object.
I would like to modify the content provider on runtime. Is this possible?
This is the androidManifest.xml
<provider
        android:name=".MyContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.i.sticker_admin.mycontentprovider"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:readPermission="com.whatsapp.sticker.READ" />

I tried this in the MainActivity.java:
MyContentProvider myContentProvider = new MyContentProvider();
ArrayList<String> newUris = new ArrayList<>();
myContentProvider.addNewUris(newUris);

This code should add some information to an internal variable in the MyContentProvider, but it do not happen. The previous code creates a new MyContentProvider instead of modifying the one declared on the AndroidManifest.xml.

"I would like to add more URIs on runtime" -- what do you mean by this? "This doesn't work" -- if it did work, what would "work" mean? What impact would it have?

I don't have access to the contentprovider declared in the Androidmanifest.xml. That one in the example is other that I created, they are not the same
